# how can show all markers on google map(API v3)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to show all markers on google map , but the looping only show the last record. How can fix it?

```
function initMap() {
     for (i = 0; i < markers.length ; i++) { 
        var location = {lat: markers[i][0], lng: markers[i][1]};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 10,
          center: location
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          // prevent the user move the marker
          draggable: false,
          map: map
        });
      }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the map each time in the loop. Due to this only the last marker is seen. Move the code of creating the map outside the loop.

```
function initMap() {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: {lat: markers[0][0], lng: markers[0][1]}
    });

 for (i = 0; i < markers.length ; i++) { 
    var location = {lat: markers[i][0], lng: markers[i][1]};

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      // prevent the user move the marker
      draggable: false,
      map: map
    });
  }
 }
```

If you want the map to be zoomed in to view all the markers then you can use the [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) class.